# Android Application Attack Surface Analyzer (A3SA)

Tags: android, python, security, android-manifest, apk

I'm working on a report of a security laboratory named quarkslab.
They made a report about Android OEM security. ->

http://www.quarkslab.com/dl/Android-OEM-applications-insecurity-and-backdoors-without-permission.pdf

In a another report they talk about a python script named A3SA (Android Application Attack Surface Analyzer). It analyzes the content of the AndroidManifest.xml file and apply different rules on each of the components (depending on their type) to see if it is exported and under what conditions.
Whenever I look for this script, I can't find it.

Does anyone know where I can find it? Or is it an unpublished script, written by the lab ?

Thank you in advance for your time and answers.